# Multiple field sort_by combination of reverse and not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

So I got this array of object from database and I have to sort it in order:

1. by score (reverse)
2. by count (reverse)
3. by name

I've tried all three in reverse but what I need is the last one should not be reverse (DESC) here's my code:

```
new_data = data.sort_by{ |t| [t.score, t.matches_count, t.name] }.reverse
```

**RESULT**

```
[
            {
                "id": null,
                "team_id": 939,
                "name": "DAV",
                "matches_count": 2,
                "score": 100.0
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "team_id": 964,
                "name": "SAN",
                "matches_count": 1,
                "score": 100.0
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "team_id": 955,
                "name": "PAS",
                "matches_count": 1,
                "score": 100.0
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "team_id": 954,
                "name": "PAR",
                "matches_count": 1,
                "score": 100.0
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "team_id": 952,
                "name": "NUE",
                "matches_count": 1,
                "score": 100.0
            }
        ]
```

Expected result should be sorted by name in ASC order not DESC I knew my code is wrong because the `t.name` is inside `.reverse` but if I will reorder it by `name` alone after the first 2 I will get the wrong answer it will just sort all by name not by the 3. I've also tried to `.order("name DESC")` from query so when reverse it will go ASC but no luck. Thank you!

Comment: @noname yes, I've tried that as you can see at the last part of my question it will return the data by name alone not by (score first then match then name). Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed that, so  I deleted comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [{:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>2, :name=>"DAV"},
        {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"SAN"},
        {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"PAS"},
        {:score=>110.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"PAR"},
        {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"NUE"}]
```

```
data.sort_by{ |h| [-h[:score], -h[:matches_count], h[:name]] }
  #=> [{:score=>110.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"PAR"},
  #    {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>2, :name=>"DAV"},
  #    {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"NUE"},
  #    {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"PAS"},
  #    {:score=>100.0, :matches_count=>1, :name=>"SAN"}]
```

You could also use [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sort), which does not require that values to be sorted on in descending order be numeric, so long as they are comparable, that is, so long as they respond to the method `:<=>`.

```
data.sort do |t1, t2|
  case t1[:score] <=> t2[:score]
  when -1
     1
  when  1
    -1
  else
    case t1[:matches_count] <=> t2[:matches_count]
    when -1
       1
    when  1
      -1
    else
      t1[:name] <=> t2[:name]
    end
  end
end
  #=> <as above>
```

Comment: I didn't think using - instead of .reverse what I've tried earlier is ```data.sort_by{ |t| [t.score.reverse, t.matches_count.reverse, t.name] } ``` that's why it returns ```undefined method `reverse'``` Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-` one can also try to reverse the sort using `!` as demonstrated here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/sort-by-multiple-fields-with-reverse-sort/197361/2

So in your case, you could do:

```
new_data = data.sort_by{ |t| [!t.score, !t.matches_count, t.name] }
```

which should give you the same result as intended.